# MVC 4 kendo control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi I am new to Mvc I am trying to add kendo in visual studio but I am finding this following error.

CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' and no extension method 'Kendo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I followed all the steps from the link http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-4 
but I am still getting this error. Can anyone please resolve this issue for me?

Comment: Have you installed the Kendo mvc library?

Comment: I have downloaded Telerik on my pc. Can you please guide me what is the use of kendo library?

Comment: UI for ASP.NET MVC Q3 2015, Kendo UI Professional Q3 2015 I have these files on my pc after downloading the telerik

Comment: You need a reference to the kendo.mvc.dll in your project as indicated in your link. If you expand the reference on your web project do you see Kendo.Mvc in the list?

Comment: Yes I do see kendo.Mvc list .. Why  am  i still getting this error?    CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' and no extension method 'Kendo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have a using statement on the view? @using Kendo.Mvc.UI Instead, do a reference in web.config located in root of View folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478474/how-can-i-use-kendo-ui-with-razor

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I added kendo reference in web config and it worked out for me..